# Run multiple commands in linux without logging as root user?

Tags: shell, unix, command, sudo

I want to write a script, i want to run from non-root user, the script contains multiple commands.

```
For EX: 
sudo -i
hostname
df -h
```

I tried the same 3 commands in a script but it's logging to root user and not executing `hostname` and `df -h` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run command with root privileges use

```
sudo command,
```

command

```
 sudo -i
```

will log you to root's shell.
If you want to run multiple commands you should use

command1 && command2

it runs command2 after command1 is sucesuflly finished.

If you need root's privileges in your script maybe you should use sudo when executing your script, and in your script check if user has necessary  privileges (http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/shell-root-user-check-script.html).

Comment: Hi, Is there any way, because if it ran sudo -i, it's going to root terminal, so next commands in script is not running untill i exit root terminal. My intention is to run the commands in the script to run under root terminal

Comment: Use `sudo command` without -i. You should use sudo for each command which you want to run as root (or sudo for entire script - but remember that **all** commands will be run as root).